# typescript pull type out of type with generic ex TypedDocumentNode<MyType, unknown>

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am using a library which I can get a type from a returned variable on the function.

```
const myVar = gql(somestring) // gql is the library function
type myVarType = typeof myVar

// myVarType = TypedDocumentNode<TypeIWant, Unknown>

type WantedType = ??
```

What I want to get is as a type variable equal to `TypeIWant` extracted from TypedDocumentNode.
Not sure this is possible.  still learning the more advanced uses of typescript.

for reference, using the codegen library for graphql

Answer (score 0):

So the way I solved it is using this

```
type extracted<D> = D extends TypedDocumentNode<infer T, any> ? T : never
type Teamstore = extracted<typeof MyTestFragVariable>
```

The extracted type is reusable so could put this all together but in my case I will use it for other things.
This is using infer to pull the type out from the main type I had.

Article that helped
https://itnext.io/typescript-extract-unpack-a-type-from-a-generic-baca7af14e51

Turns out asking the question helped figure out the right keywords to find the answer.